# How to neatly avoid C casts losing truth

Tags: c, coding-style

I'm quite happy that, in C, things like this are bad code:

```
(var_a == var_b) ? TRUE : FALSE
```

However, what's the best way of dealing with this:

```
/* Header stuff */
#define INTERESTING_FLAG 0x80000000
typedef short int BOOL;

void func(BOOL);

/* Code */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        unsigned long int flags = 0x00000000;

        ... /* Various bits of flag processing */

        func(flags & INTERESTING_FLAG); /* func never receives a non-zero value
                                         * as the top bits are cut off when the
                                         * argument is cast down to a short 
                                         * int
                                         */
}
```

Is it acceptable (for whatever value of acceptable you're using) to have `(flags & FLAG_CONST) ? TRUE : FALSE`?

Comment: I think the problem here is `#define BOOL short int`. You've defined a so-called boolean type, but where non-zero values convert to it as false. Then you've acted as if any non-zero value is true. That's some leaky abstraction.

Comment: I dont really see what's bad about that code, it's a standard language feature any C programmer should know about.

Comment: @Skizz: the problem with `(var1 == var2) ? TRUE : FALSE;` you mean? The problem is it's better expressed as `(var1 == var2)`, assuming TRUE and FALSE have sensible values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd prefer `(flags & CONST_FLAG) != 0`. Better still, use the _Bool type if you have it (though it's often disguised as `bool`).

Comment: Does `_Bool`/`bool` map all non-zero values to `true`, then? I've not heard of it before…

Comment: @me_and:yes, a cast to _Bool/bool makes all non-zero values true, and zero false. It was added in C99, but since C++ also has `bool`, a fair number of C compilers include it as well, even though they don't implement (even close to) all of C99.

Comment: Accepting: has a good pre-C99 option (that I'm probably going to have to use; I need to be able to build on non-C99 compilers, sadly), and has the ideal standards-supplied solution too :D

Answer (score 6):

I would in either case called func with `(flags & INTERESTING_FLAG) != 0` as an argument to indicate that a boolean parameter is required and not the arithmetic result of `flags & INTERESTING_FLAG`.

Comment: I'm vaguely partial to ((flags & MASK) == MASK) as a general solution, but it should give the same result as != 0.

Comment: @vatine: That does have the disadvantage that comparisons to non-zero values are (very marginally) less efficient than comparisons to zero, as a comparison to zero can generally be implemented as a single machine operation. Doesn't make much of a difference (and with a good compiler it may well make no difference at all), but still…

Comment: @me_and: No difference at all with the two compilers I just tried.  It's a pretty simple transform for a compiler to get.

Answer (score 4):

Set your compiler flags as anally as possible, to warn you of any cast that loses bits, and treat warnings as errors.

Comment: +1.  This doesn't tell you what to do about it, but it is important.

Answer (score 4):

Some people don't like it, but I use !!.

ie

```
!!(flags & CONST_FLAG)
```

(not as a to_bool macro as someone else suggested, just straight in the code).

*If more people used it, it wouldn't be seen as unusual* so start using it!!

Comment: I don't think it's odd or unusual, I just don't like it. I prefer named operators where possible (`and` instead of `&&`, `not` instead of `!`) and if I saw someone write `not not x` in Python I would shoot them. The symbol version is more readable, but I still don't like it, which is why I put it in a macro.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a popular solution, but sometimes macros are useful.

```
#define to_bool(x) (!!(x))
```

Now we can safely have anything we want without fear of overflowing our type:

```
func(to_bool(flags & INTERESTING_FLAG));
```

Another alternative might be to define your boolean type to be an `intmax_t` (from `stdint.h`) so that it's impossible for a value to be truncated into falseness.

While I'm here, I want to say that you should be using a `typedef` for defining a new type, not a `#define`:

```
typedef short Bool; // or whatever type you end up choosing
```

Some might argue that you should use a `const` variable instead of a macro for numeric constants:

```
const INTERESTING_FLAG = 0x80000000;
```

Overall there are better things you can spend your time on. But macros for `typedef`s is a bit silly.

Comment: Good spot. I used `typedef` in my code, and completely forgot about its very existence when writing this question!

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid this a couple different ways:

First off

```
void func(unsigned long int);
```

would take care of it...

Or

```
if(flags & INTERESTING_FLAG)
{
  func(true);
}
else
{
  func(false);
}
```

would also do it.

EDIT: `(flags & INTERESTING_FLAG) != 0` is also good.  Probably better.

Answer (score 0):

This is partially off topic:

I'd also create a help function that makes it obvious to the reader what the purpose of the check is so you don't fill your code with this explicit flag checking all over the place. Typedefing the flag type would make it easier to change flag type and implementation later.

Modern compilers supports the inline keyword that can get rid of the performance overhead in a function call.

```
typedef unsigned long int flagtype;
...
inline bool hasInterestingFlag(flagtype flags) {
   return ((flags & INTERESTING_FLAG) != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything against

```
 flags & INTERESTING_FLAG ? TRUE : FALSE
```

?

Answer (score 0):

This is why you should only use values in a "boolean" way when these values have explicitly boolean semantics. Your value does not satisfy taht rule, since it has a pronounced integer semantics (or, more precisely, bit-array semantics). In order to convert such a value to boolean, compare it to `0`

```
func((flags & INTERESTING_FLAG) != 0);
```